# How can i create a RESTFul application which uses Apache Spark, specially Streaming at the back end

Tags: java, apache-spark, architecture, streaming, restful-architecture

I am quiet new to Apache Spark. I want to have a RESTFul service which receives a file (Large file) with Apache Spark to process this file in near real-time at the back-end.  I want to implement this in Java.

1. What are the suggested light weight framworks?
2. how can i pack this application (distribution). Say i have a server
   (e.g. Tomcat). Should i pack Spark inside the Webservice ?
3. How can i run the Spark cluster programmatically? Like a service
       which is always up and down on demand.
4. Is there any samples which follow this kind of architecture or implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Akka HTTP](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.3/scala/http/) to implement REST services.
Complete working example of how to integrate Akka and Spark is [killrweather](https://github.com/killrweather/killrweather).

Comment: Thanks for the link Rado. It would be more helpful if it is in Java. Above one is in Scala. However I see that Akka has support for both Java and Scala. So i think i can learn the basics from it.

Comment: Hi @NehaM did you come up with a different solution for your problem or you end up using the proposed solution by Rado  ? Thanks

Comment: @Mero I used Rado's example to get an idea about the solution. I had to use other alternatives since i have different language requirement. So my solution has Spark services wrapped by `Clojure` and i used `Ring server` to expose it as a web service.

Comment: @NehaM thanks :) i think i will try http://Livy.io for now and see how i get on with it

Comment: @Mero Sounds like a good choice.